# automatically update a list from TreeView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, treeview

I want to ask opinion of how should I implement the solution in this case.

```
DataItem A = someDataItem;
DataItem B = someDataItem;
DataItem C = someDataItem;
DataItem D = someDataItem;

//CreateNode : this function convert the DataItem into TreeNode
TreeNode nodeA = CreateNode(A);
TreeNode nodeB = CreateNode(B);
TreeNode nodeC = CreateNode(C);
TreeNode nodeD = CreateNode(D);

//add the nodes to a TreeView component here
treeView.Nodes.Add(nodeA);
treeView.Nodes.Add(nodeB);
treeView.Nodes.Add(nodeC);
treeView.Nodes.Add(nodeD);

List<DataItem> specialWatchedNodeList = new List<DataItem>();
specialWatchedNode.Add(nodeA);
specialWatchedNode.Add(nodeD);
```

I have the `treeView` which contain all the nodes. However, I have only some of them that I want to be monitored (to be watched) => (`nodeA` and `nodeD`). If anything happen to `nodeA` and `nodeD` in the `treeView`, how should I update `nodeA` and `nodeD` in the `specialWatchedNodeList`?

Comment: Is this winforms, asp, WPF, silverlight, windows phone, or what?

Comment: windows form application

Answer (score 1):

You can receive an event whenever a DataItem changes by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the class DataItem.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You'll need to declare the *PropertyChanged* event and then create the *OnPropertyChanged* method. For each property you want change notifications for, you call *OnPropertyChanged* whenever the property is updated.